# How does an array of all duplicates make quicksort O(N^2)?

Tags: quicksort

In my data structures & algorithms class we learned about 3-scan and Hoare's partitioning algorithms. I was told that we get the worst case of O(N^2) on an array of all duplicates.

However, I don't understand why an array of all duplicates give the worst-case time of N^2, I understand why choosing the min/max as the pivot give worst-case but hopefully someone can explain the duplicates case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Lomuto partition or similar partition schemes have the issue where all duplicates results in time complexity of O(n^2).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

With Hoare partition scheme, there will be needless swaps of equal elements, but the partitioning will be an ideal 50% / 50% split, so O(log2(n)) (the constant 2 is not normally included for time complexity, but I'm including it here to indicate the ideal splitting of partitions). In general, as the percentage of duplicates increases, the time it takes for Hoare partition based quick sort to sort decreases.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme